# Spring выборка полей отличающихся только языком по хэдеру

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

Используется SpringBoot+PostgreSQL, в базе данных есть множество полей содержащих в себе одинаковую информацию на разных языках и имеющие схожие названия (пример: name_ru, name_en, name_ch). При запросе отправляется языковой хэдер, который и должен определять какое именно из трех полей будет выбрано (только одно) в Dto, каким образом можно автоматизировать выборку необходимых полей при запросе к БД, без последующего маппинга, или же упростить данный процесс?

Comment: репозиторий на основе `JdbcTemplate` с трёмя методами и общим маппером. ну и дёргайте тот метод, который нужен.

Comment: Если структуру БД можно поменять, то я бы все языковые поля заменил на поле типа [jsonb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301896) (типа: `{"en": "hello", "ru": "привет",...}`). Если нельзя, то использовал бы MyBatis - он позволяет строить запросы [динамически](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html) (на всякий случай - [мой пример работы с батисом](https://bit.ly/2LIt5zD)). Ну или сделал бы функцию в Постгресе (в которой строил запрос [динамически](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710523)), и использовал ее в нативном Query в репозитории...